# Css transform - how to fit entirely rotated page on screen?

Tags: css, rotation, transform

Is it in any way possible to rotate the entire webpage 90 degres and then fit the screen size? When I do the `transform:rotate(90deg);` the width and height ratio is the same as before.

How can I fit the HTML element inside the screen after rotating?

HTML:

```
<div id="red">
    Content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#red {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    background-color:#ff0000;

}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVL8T/)

Comment: maybe flip your 'width' / 'height' ?

Comment: Howe would you do that?

Comment: its not as easy as it sounds.. and you'll need to use javascript, do you know jquery?

Comment: Ok, so basically you need a function to calculate your width and height before the transform happens and then set them after.. you'll probably need to tweak the transform-origin and maybe use negative margin or offset to position your content back into place but on its side.

Comment: The problem with negative margin is that the contents size is not fixed. So it would not always be the same.

Comment: yes.. you would have to calculate the size in order to calculate the margin..